# Flutter/Dart : synchronous way to read file in asset folder

Tags: file, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am trying to read JSON file in assets folder and deserializing it to object.
`String fromJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/File.json');`
deserialization function is async so it returns even before actually reading JSON file and deserializing it. that's why there are multiple calls happening to this deserialization function from different places in project.

All async calls are queued before executing first await call ie. `await rootBundle.loadString('assets/File.json');` so the file is being read multiple times.

Is there a way to wait for file to read or wait till deserialization happens and then return back to the caller of deserialization function? or synchronous way to read file in asset folder ?
I want file to read only once and wait for deserialization to happen.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In general reading the file asynchronously should not be a problem at all and is actually recommended. You don't want to block the UI while waiting for the file to be loaded and parsed.

So this means you probably have a small mistake in your code that is causing this problem. Since you didn't list any code I cannot really pin point the problem but I do have an example that I have been using which might help you.

In my example App (which you can find [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-meetup/tree/master/slurp/final)) I use the following JSON file (the actual file is bigger but this gives you an idea):

**places.json**

```json
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 52.221525,
                    "lng": 6.895323999999999
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 52.2231135302915,
                        "lng": 6.897867100000001
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 52.2204155697085,
                        "lng": 6.894476299999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
            "id": "6e274492c5dfc4100a68d47e70d8f69e1bbef40a",
            "name": "Fellini Enschede",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 3024,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109213220123895357242/photos\">Martijn Hoppenbrouwer</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAPhSAiB4-VuS-AmUdRxjBUIooQJg68zdQyLRmPJGOB7G_2xh9deq3lcI9ChPnlaTZPmQtUQ_uBqWenNLif0Okqqr5ErAGPBlhoIpcbW6iBt0Uto1qjOjRPuWTRrrL_imlEhDjC25hFY3jKzMU04ZbXUaqGhQh13kxVLaYj-aNxDnsqWfRvfWFBA",
                    "width": 4032
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ8XcydnMUuEcRCFdOhmTnLsY",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "6VCW+J4 Enschede, Netherlands",
                "global_code": "9F486VCW+J4"
            },
            "rating": 4.1,
            "reference": "CmRSAAAAtmshr7ZCjO5X5Zb8ZHNGgek6CzPUBXHBEtP7AR_A8vg10GMpcMCdk_S1Y141Nv5G3f7ed9XFPaSjU6aR_lHoJ6PwNx3lQL7HJf9ai9G2aExbs5KHuwacwTqUV3ocI1RkEhDWe_4cklgqwe94iyEOg4fNGhSZL88S4ZAde2kWm0VAwm8gObCCjg",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "night_club",
                "bar",
                "restaurant",
                "food",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "2, Bolwerkstraat, Enschede"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 52.22302359999999,
                    "lng": 6.893403099999998
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 52.22446798029149,
                        "lng": 6.894722280291502
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 52.22177001970849,
                        "lng": 6.892024319708497
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
            "id": "a18ff7853e5f6eb545fcb93fd55c85cf915bd301",
            "name": "'T Bölke",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 1152,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115418315198000399419/photos\">&#39;t Bölke</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAhRaUOljchj6XFtlC7sB-93l4pfcEMTClAG6pZbPkE4KQ64Y9kPY0cAZ6uozFJdD_aB7BHPfIbhY2EU-47b8v_lWjaZcaQX_YIhh1Hqbz9tMCv-brLfxYzykbpfYMVaa2EhD_9RqnDMDDYjzR_lJvYW_UGhQi4dnTzDTgIiaRHNVrlmfv28qRvw",
                    "width": 2048
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJX2MAvHQUuEcRY9HmmyKX1oI",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "6VFV+69 Enschede, Netherlands",
                "global_code": "9F486VFV+69"
            },
            "rating": 4.1,
            "reference": "CmRSAAAAZ-3uQbzsSLjQRshhJ9L6J7iOOMV2T7HL-ELqrufGKXflCbVHaEDD3-eNoAvVsF0k4muHAQT-rQaf-bYPFuy3BafMyLzMnscR1cTuCVwpLvo-Gh9O62PJmhMtSqbcJvoCEhDVHVVCEIxrmEhHY96ucRlHGhTAU1zn9KcPxRsZslAvinU1mBmtSQ",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "night_club",
                "bar",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Molenstraat 6-8, Enschede"
        }
    ]
}
```

Next I have a helper Dart file which defines the `Place` class and contains a method that will read the file and transforms the JSON items into instances of the `Place` class, which looks like this:

**places.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Place {
  final String name;
  final double rating;
  final String address;

  Place.fromJson(Map jsonMap) : 
    name = jsonMap['name'],
    rating = jsonMap['rating']?.toDouble() ?? -1.0,
    address = jsonMap['vicinity'];

  String toString() => 'Club: $name';
}

Future<Stream<Place>> getPlaces() async {
  return new Stream.fromFuture(rootBundle.loadString('assets/places.json'))
    .transform(json.decoder)
    .expand((jsonBody) => (jsonBody as Map)['results'])
    .map((jsonPlace) => new Place.fromJson(jsonPlace));
}
```

And finally I have a very simple UI that will call the `getPlaces` method and show al records in a `ListView`:

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'places.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Slurp',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Slurp'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<Place> _places = <Place>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    listenForPlaces();
  }

  void listenForPlaces() async {
    var stream = await getPlaces();

    stream.listen(
      (place) => 
        setState(
          () => _places.add(place)
        )
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
          children: _places.map((place) => new PlaceWidget(place)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlaceWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Place place;

  PlaceWidget(this.place);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ratingColor = Color.lerp(Colors.red, Colors.green, place.rating / 5);

    var listTile = new ListTile(
      leading: new CircleAvatar(
        child: new Text(place.rating.toString()),
        backgroundColor: ratingColor,
      ),
      title: new Text(place.name),
      subtitle: new Text(place.address),
    );

    return new Dismissible(
      key: new Key(place.name),
      background: new Container(color: Colors.green),
      secondaryBackground: new Container(color: Colors.red),
      onDismissed: (dir) {
        if(dir == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
          print("You liked ${place.name}");
        } else {
          print("You didn't like ${place.name}");
        }
      },
      child: listTile,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a framework design problem. You can't make build async and you can't only load async. So to make it work you have to chase the geese around the barn and scratch your head for a while.

Comment: @micahhoover It is true that flutter doesn't give you a "choice".  To say it's a "problem" is wrong though.  It's an intentional choice, if any widget could hold up the "frame" because it wanted to for whatever reason, it allows people to do things that are bad in almost every case except where you as a final application developer want to choose to be lazy (fair).  Reflection is similar, it'd be nice if flutter supported it, but flutter doesn't so that flutter apps will be performant and no package maintainer will cut corners.

Comment: It makes plenty of sense to say "we need to render a frame now", but to me, it seems like you're saying "I want to be able to make my program freeze rather than render frames".  It's not that much harder to just:

if (!lloaded) return CircularProgressIndicator()